# $.getJSON call returns all lowercase

Tags: jquery

I am calling a GET request to my nodejs server and receiving a JSON result object.  I am wondering why the content of the object is all lower case?  Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stories").click(function(){                
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/stories",function(data,status){                      
              $("#users").html("<table>");
              $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $("#users").append("<tr><td>" + item.name +"</td></tr><tr> <td>" + item.role + "</td></tr>");
              });                     
              $("#users").append("</table>");                                          
        });
    });
});
```

JSON object being sent from the server to the client:

```
var myData = 
{
    "name": "Jon Doe",
    "role": "Developer"
};
res.send(myData);
```

Comment: is this perhaps a node.js (rather than jQuery) issue?

Comment: what do you see when you `console.log` or `console.dir` the data within the getJSON callback?

Comment: It appears that you are returning an object but interating over it as if it was an array. Don't you mean to say `$.each(data,function(key,value){...})`

Comment: Sorry disregard; I needed to change the format of my JSON object:

    var myData = 
    {   "users": {
          "name": "Jon Doe",
          "role": "Developer"
        }
    };
    res.send(myData);

Comment: Check in Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools - what is actually getting received from the server?